# glmnet giving different sequence of lambda values than inputted

Tags: r, machine-learning, glmnet

This is a weird issue that I am unsure as to what is happening. When I use cv.glmnet, I input a sequence of lambdas, but sometimes it seems to give me a different sequence in the fitted model. I am trying to find an average MSE vs lambda curve from a bunch of k-fold runs so this causing a lot of issues for me. Right now, I have:

```
ridge = function(trax, tray, lambda, folds)
{
  folds_ids = array(dim=length(tray))
  for (f in 1:length(folds))
  {
    folds_ids[folds[[f]]] = f
  }
  cvfit = cv.glmnet(trax,
                tray,
                alpha=0,
                lambda=lambda,
                family='binomial',
                foldid=folds_ids,
                parallel=TRUE)
  return(cvfit)
}
ridge_lambda = seq(5e-1,1e-5,length=100)
ridge_result = ridge(trax=training_featr, 
                   tray=training_class, 
                   lam = ridge_lambda, 
                   folds = kfolds)
```

Right now, ridge_result$lambda and ridge_result$cvm sometimes give vectors that are 99 elements instead of 100. I have no idea why. I appreciate any help I can get.

Answer (score 0):

`glmnet` is very well written and there's a lot going on behind the scenes to try to make your life easier. In this case, I think there are two factors at play:

1. The folds are selected randomly each time, which explains why you're seeing this sometimes and not others.
2. From the [glmnet vignette](https://web.stanford.edu/~hastie/glmnet/glmnet_alpha.html), "the program stops early if `%dev% does not change sufficently from one lambda to the next (typically near the end of the path.)"

Combine these two features of the package you end up with the results you're seeing.

In practice, I'd recommend providing and `nlambda` instead of your own series, as that is what the authors recommend, since `cv.glmnet` will generate the lambda series on a log scale for you.